# How to sort collection of objects using its property?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

[image: Unsorted collection-picture]

Want to use these in ng-repeat. 
How to sort them using id property ?

Comment: A picture may be worth a thousand words, that does not apply when it is a picture of text. Please include the actual JSON in your question. It saves me from having to type JSON in an answer. If would also be helpful if you include some code of what you already tried in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to build a Firebase query to handle the ordering:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com');
var query = ref.child('Denovi').orderByChild('id');
var list = $firebaseArray(query);
```

Read more about these queries here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

You might want to consider storing the items under their id, which makes the (potentially expensive) re-ordering unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort an object. The ideal way would be to store the objects in an array and ng-repeat over the array with the following filter:

```
orderBy: 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak what I assume to be Russian, so it's hard to tell what the collection looks like and how you intend to use it within the `ng-repeat`.  The `orderBy` filter is what you need to sort a collection though.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in Denovi | orderBy: 'id'">
    {{item.id}}
</div>
```